# Can Local Build Deployment Settings Be Changed in VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

**A Little Background:**
My team has a somewhat outdated ASP.NET MVC solution that I have been tasked with upgrading as current as possible. We're migrating up from MVC 2 and WebPages (ASPX/ASCX) to MVC 4. The solution is rather large (20+ projects) and most of it is working properly. We have run into an issue though where some of the aspx pages throw the compiler error:

```
> "BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'some_extended_view_name_here'...
```

Most of the digging I came up with on the issue recommends that when publishing, you unselect "allow this precompiled site to be updatable". Problem is that when running locally via the "Run/Run Without Debugging" buttons, you aren't publishing per-se. So...

**TL/DR:** Is there any way to change the 'publish' settings when using the run or run w/out debugging buttons for MVC websites in Visual Studio 2012/2013? I have looked and looked, but can't find anything suggesting it's even possible.

Comment: When you "upgrade" the ASPX/ASCX, are you converting them to Web Forms pages and controls? Or Razor pages and partials (.cshtml)?

Comment: @mason Haven't converted any of them I believe, unless the MVC 2 to MVC 3 wizard did. They are all still ASPX/ASCX pages. Most of them work fine, but a few stubborn pages keep throwing the error about InitializeCulture.

Comment: On a side note, I'd like to see us move over to using Razor, but we're talking hundreds of views that (as far as I can tell) would have to be manually changed.